# Nested ListView not visibile - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two list view. One is a wrapper of all the widgets in the view, the second one is a child of it.
Here is the code:

```
ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: [
                      Container(
                         ................
                          ),
                      Container(
                         ................
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Expanded(child: Column(children: [
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.black12,
                              height: 20,
                              thickness: 1,
                              indent: 20,
                              endIndent: 0,
                            ),
                            Row(children: [
                              Image.network(
                                  "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"),
                              Text(Utils.days[index + 1],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                      fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white))
                            ]),
                          ]));
                        },
                        itemCount: 5,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      )
                    ]);
```

The two containers are visible. I can't see the items inside the second list view. There isn't any error in the console. I have no idea why is this happening.

Comment: do not nest two or more `ListView`s - instead use `CustomScrollView`

Comment: add `shrinkWrap: true` below second list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding shrinkWrap: true and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to the nested ListView

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this code will work for you.

```
      return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            // physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("one"),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text("two"),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(children: [
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black12,
                        height: 20,
                        thickness: 1,
                        indent: 20,
                        endIndent: 0,
                      ),
                      Row(children: [
                        Image.network(
                            "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"),
                        Text(index.toString(),
                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white))
                      ]),
                    ]);
                  },
                  itemCount: 5,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                ),
              )
            ]),
      )),
    );
```